# Como fazer uma animação em uma tela de "Splash"?

Tags: android

Alguém aí tem alguma ideia de como crio uma animação estilo o [aplicativo da Caixa](https://youtu.be/2kQlNrCP5vs)?
Eu já criei uma animação com imagem, mas gostaria de fazer estilo o app da caixa. Alguém sabe como funciona isso?

Comment: Como é o app da Caixa?

Comment: Olá, Artur. Seria mais interessante você descrever em palavras o que quer, já que nem todo mundo que segue perguntas sobre Android conhece o aplicativo da Caixa. Note que esse não é um site apenas para brasileiros, mas para qualquer um que fale português.

Comment: @ArturMafezzoliJúnior tem como tirar um print e enviar aqui, para a gente saber como é essa animação?

Comment: Eai galera. Desculpa ai. Vou tirar um print e postar aqui. Mas não sei se vai adiantar muito, pois como é animação o print vai tirar apenas uma foto.

Comment: Galera, fiz um video para entenderem melhor. Ignorem as falas ali, fiz rapidão aqui na empresa. Segue o link. https://youtu.be/2kQlNrCP5vs

Comment: Boa tarde pessoal. Alguém conseguiu dá uma olhada ali no video? Peço desculpas, pois o vídeo gravei meio que as pressas. Mas dá pra ver certinho. Andei verificando aqui acho que o que passa no começo do aplicativo da Caixa é um vídeo. Mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Boa tarde Galera. Não sei se é permitido isso aqui e sei também que existe milhares de perguntas aqui. Mas será que alguém, se deparou com essa minha dúvida e conseguiu resolver ? Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

qual plataforma de desenvolvimento você está utilizando?

Bom, basicamente você precisaria de um elemento de renderização, como o canvas em html, se não me engano, o MIT App Inventor possui um chamado 'pintura'.

Com isso, seria necessário inserir os elementos que você quer que sejam mostrados, no efeito de slide.

Então bastaria você inseri-los na ordem que quer e decrementar a posição deles na 'tela', como o simbolo da caixa se torna fixo no final, você precisaria de uma verificação para faze-lo parar de se mover

Espero ter ajudado :)